# Run Jenkins on different port on a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to run Jenkins on docker by using a different port. By default Jenkins is running on port 8080, but this port is used by different service in my machine. I would like to run Jenkins on a different port.

I have used the following command without any success:

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  --name jenkins \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  --env JAVA_OPTS="--httpPort=8081" \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What would you consider "success" and what instead are you seeing / experiencing?

Comment: if the ip of the machine is e.g. 192.168.184.54, then I would expect to browse on http://192.168.184.54:8081 and see the service of jenkins

Comment: Have you tried to let the container run on the default port (`8080`) and bind it to `8081` on the host? Something like `-p 8081:8080`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
docker run \
  -u root \
  --rm \
  -d \
  --name jenkins \
  -p 8081:8080 \
  -p 50000:50000 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Comment: without  `--env JAVA_OPTS="--httpPort=8081"`

Comment: Note that this way jenkins will most probably generate wrong absolute urls for outside use (such as emails).

Answer (score 8):

```
--env JAVA_OPTS="--httpPort=8081" \
```

not JAVA_OPTS, change it like this:

```
-e JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=8081"
```

Comment: Yes. this will make your container port change to 8081 and you can use -p 8081:8081